# How to update gdm3

Tags: 18.04

I found that gdm3 has vulnerabilities:
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2018-August/004530.html

but I'm not able to update gdm3 to the version `3.28.2-0ubuntu1.4`:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install gdm3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gdm3 is already the newest version (3.28.0-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried to remove gdm3 and fresh install but it still installs in version 3.28.0.

There is any way I can update gdm3 package? My Linux is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Hi Mariusz!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Have you done an `sudo apt update` before you called `apt-get`?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gdm3  3.28.3 is in the security repository so it should update but you need to update the index with `sudo apt update` first.

Comment: Yes, I've already done `sudo apt update`. There was many hints and warning but I don't know what they mean. After all there were info `All packages are up to date.` so I guess everything is up to date. Maybe I'm missing some of the repositories?

Comment: If it's a fresh install, the security repos should already be enabled.  Maybe check the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure there's `bionic-security` on the line of each repos. Something like this: `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic-security main ....`

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt update`, please. Are you on a Raspberry Pi or something? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gdm3 says the newest version for ARM systems is indeed `3.28.0-0ubuntu1`

Comment: It is no clean install. I've added `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/ bionic-security main` because I did not found `bionic-security` repository but after `sudo apt-get update` I'm getting `Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu bionic-security Release                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]`

Comment: Edit your question and include the full output of `sudo apt update` if you are getting lots of warnings, you should not do anything else in `apt` until you sort out your problems with your package manager. Otherwise, you're likely to cause new problems.